# Understanding basics of reach router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I am trying to understand basics of [reach](https://reach.tech/router) router and have doubts on following code

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Logo from "./Logo";
import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router";

let Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link> |{" "}
      <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
    </nav>

  </div>
)

let Dash = () => <div>Dash</div>



render(<Router>
  <Home path="/" />
  <Dash path="dashboard" />
</Router>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I know that this Router works as `Switch` from router 4, i.e., renders only one path inside router.
Now when I start the app initially I am inside `Home`, e.g. here

```
<div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link> |{" "}
      <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
    </nav>

  </div>
```

At this moment it is my belief that `Dashboard` component hasn't been rendered anywhere. However, if I type `dashboard` in URL or click the above link it correctly takes me to `Dashboard` component.

My question is how does algorithm of resolving to Dashboard works in this case?
**Does it "restart" the app and see that there was a component registered for "dashboard" route initially?**
My point is because when I am at home location there is nothing on the page anymore that indicates that Dashboard component is registered under dashboard route, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`<Router>`'s internal implementation uses `history.listen()` (https://github.com/reach/router/blob/master/src/index.js#L103) which in turn listens to native `popstate` events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate). You can see it in action [here](https://github.com/reach/router/blob/master/src/index.js#L103).

It looks like your intuitions are indeed right. `<Router>` component is history-aware by listening to history changes. It re-renders routes as a result of internal `setState` calls.

I can recommend going though the source code if you'd like to know even more about implementation details.